# Find related names in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns, name and related_name.

```
CREATE TABLE _test(
[name] NVARCHAR(50),
related_name NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo._test
([name], related_name)
VALUES

('a', 'b'),
('b', 'c'),
('c', 'd'),
('e', 'f'),
('f', 'g')
```

I want to write a UDF, which will get a name and will return all the related names. If a is related with b and b is related with c this means that a is related with c.

So the expected result for parameter 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' must be the same.

```
select * from my_func('a')
```

The result must be

```
result
------
a
b
c
d
```

And the result for

```
select * from my_func('e')
```

must be

```
result
------
e
f
g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this, provided you don't have more than 100 relations (since you can't add `MAXRECURSION` inside the function, so you'd have to apply it on any query that references the function - [see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428903/61305)).

The first step is to find all the parent-less parents, then use that as an anchor for recursion.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@input nvarchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN
  (
    WITH Parents(name) AS
    (
      -- find parent-less parents:
      SELECT name FROM dbo._test
      EXCEPT 
      SELECT related_name FROM dbo._test
    ),
    children AS
    (
      -- use parents as anchor
      SELECT orig = name, name FROM Parents
      UNION ALL
      SELECT c.orig, related_name 
        FROM dbo._test AS t
        INNER JOIN children AS c
        ON c.name = t.name
    )
    SELECT name 
    FROM children AS o
    -- now filter only to a single, common anchor
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM children WHERE name = @input AND orig = o.orig
    )
  );
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT name FROM dbo.my_func(N'b');
```

Results:

```
name
----
a
b
c
d
```

Of course it is easy to break this with a circular reference. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

**The query (both ways):**

```
declare @name nvarchar(50) = N'd'
;WITH CTE AS
(
(select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where name = @name
UNION
select name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where related_name = @name)
UNION ALL 
select t1.name, t1.related_name from dbo._test t1
INNER JOIN CTE on cte.related_name = t1.name 
),
 CTE2 AS
(
(select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where name = @name
UNION 
select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where related_name = @name)
UNION ALL 
select t1.name, t1.related_name from dbo._test t1
INNER JOIN CTE2 on t1.related_name = cte2.name 
)

select DISTINCT name  from cte
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT cte.related_name from cte 
UNION
select DISTINCT name  from cte2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT cte2.related_name from cte2
```

**Result:**

```
 name
e
f
g
```

**As a  table valued function:**

```
ALTER function dbo.my_func(@name nvarchar(50))
    returns table
    as

    RETURN
    (WITH CTE AS
(
(select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where name = @name
UNION
select name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where related_name = @name)
UNION ALL 
select t1.name, t1.related_name from dbo._test t1
INNER JOIN CTE on cte.related_name = t1.name 
),
 CTE2 AS
(
(select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where name = @name
UNION 
select  name ,  related_name from
dbo._test
where related_name = @name)
UNION ALL 
select t1.name, t1.related_name from dbo._test t1
INNER JOIN CTE2 on t1.related_name = cte2.name 
)

select DISTINCT name  from cte
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT cte.related_name from cte 
UNION
select DISTINCT name  from cte2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT cte2.related_name from cte2

)
```

**Test**

```
select * from dbo.my_func('b')
```

**Result:**

```
name
a
b
c
d
```

**Test 2**

```
select * from dbo.my_func('e')
```

**Result:**

```
name
e
f
g
```

Comment: The result for param 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' must be the same, but for 'b' we get only b, c and d,

Comment: Hi Artashes, i edited it, it should work both ways now.

Comment: Hi, the edited query works incorrect. If we pass 'c' or 'd' in returns incorrect results.

Comment: I think you read it too literally, and ignored the examples. The OP wanted related names in either direction. In your function both `c` and `d` do not work according to the OP's requirements, because `a`,`b`,`c`, and `d` should all return the same result, and they don't.

Comment: True, i did read it like that, and i should have read everything. I fixed it now to correspond to the requirements. My bad.